# Checking if Folder exists, create new Folder if not, save File from the active workbook either way

Tags: vba, excel, dir

I am working on editing some code that was written by someone else and I have had very little Excel Macro experience. I am attempting to save a file to a network location after the code completes. The person who made this program had it being saved to the wrong location and didn't have it checking if the Folder exists or not.

This is what I currently have for grabbing the file for formatting...

It needs to grab the variable file name &MA&.txt from this location...
 C:\Twist Check Vaules\&MS& &MP&\$MA%.txt

For example, if MS = TEST and MP = GO and MA = A then...
C:\Twist Check Vaules\TEST GO\A.txt

[Formats File]

Then at the end it needs to check to see if there is already a folder with the same name as the variables above but in a separate location...

Ex. Check for this folder...
O:\diaph\sdata\Blinglet\&MS& &MP&

For example, if MS = TEST and MP = GO...
O:\diaph\sdata\Blinglet\TEST GO

If this folder exists it needs to keep moving on, if not it needs to create it.

Then finally the file by the name of $MA$.txt or using the example, A.txt needs to be saved in that location...

O:\diaph\sdata\Blinglet\TEST GO

I tried looking this up myself but I have been having a lot of trouble since I am so new to excel macro.  Any help would be much appreciated!

```
 Sub Polywork_Formating_Macro()
MsgBox ("Polyworks Data Formatting: Autostart Macro in Excel")
    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim fpath As String
    Dim fname As String
    Dim MS As String
    Dim FileTitle As String
    Dim MP As String
    Dim MA As String
    Dim question As Variant
    MS = InputBox("Enter Shop Order:", "File Name")
    MP = InputBox("Enter Job Number:", "File Name")
    MA = InputBox("Enter A, B , or 360:", "File Name")
    FileTitle = " " & MA & ".xls"
    idx = 0
    fpath = "C:\Twist Check Values\" & MS & "\" & MP & "\" & MA & "\"
    fname = Dir(fpath & "*.txt")
    While (Len(fname) > 0)
        idx = idx + 1
        Sheets.Add.Name = fname`enter code here`
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
          & fpath & fname, Destination:=Range("A2"))
            .Name = "a" & idx
```

[
FORMATTING CODE IN THE MIDDLE REMOVED
]

```
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="O:\diaph\sdata\Blinglet\" & MS & "\" & MP & "\" & FileTitle & ""
    question = MsgBox("Are There AnyMore Files To Be Formated?", vbYesNo)
    If question = vbYes Then
    Workbooks.Open "C:\Stage Formatter.xlsm"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For you file path and name you need double quotes around the strings.

```
Dim strFilePath as string
str = "C:\Twist Check Vaules\" & MS & MP & "\" & MA & ".txt
```

For you filesystem functions you will need to reference the library.  In the VBA IDE go to the tools menu and select references. Select "Microsoft scripting runtime".

Then you can declare a filesystemobject.  That can be used for you folder and file functions.

```
Dim fldr As Object
Dim strFolder as string
Dim fs As FileSystemObject

Set fs = New FileSystemObject

strFolder = "C:\Twist Check Vaules\" & MS & MP & "\"

If fs.FolderExists(strFolder) = true Then
    'Do nothing
else
    msbbox ("Folder is missing")
    'or you can create it
    Set fldr = fs.CreateFolder(strFolder)

    If fldr Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the folder"
    End If
End if
```

For your text file:

```
Dim ts As TextStream

Set fs = New FileSystemObject
Set ts = fs.CreateTextFile("C:\Temp\test.txt", True, False)

ts.WriteLine "Whatever text you are writing to the file."

'Clean up
ts.Close: Set ts = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I am getting a run time error now though. "Run-time error '91': Object Variable or With block variable not set"     <code>Dim fldr As Object
Dim strFolder As String
Dim fs As FileSystemObject
   

strFolder = "O:\diaph\sdata\Blinglet\" & MS & MP & "\"

If fs.FolderExists(strFolder) = True Then
    'Do nothing
Else
    'or you can create it
    Set fldr = fs.CreateFolder(strFolder)

    If fldr Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Could not create the folder"
    End If
End If

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="O:\diaph\sdata\Blinglet\" & MS & MP & "\" & FileTitle & "\"

Comment: Was missing Set fs = New FileSystemObject in the first section if that is the way you are going to use it.  See edit above.